# How can I avoid the error "Cannot convert 'UIButtonType' to 'UIBarButtonItemStyle' in argument passing?"

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uikit, uiviewcontroller

I am incorporating zxing (qrcode scanning) into my iPhone project. I followed the instructions to make it work, which included renaming the class file from .m to .mm.

When I do this my project fails to compile with the error:  "cannot convert 'UIButtonType' to 'UIBarButtonItemStyle' in argument passing" which occurs in the following code in my class (adding a button to allow the user to invoke the scan operation)

```
// Add scan button
UIBarButtonItem *qrScanButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Scan" 
    style: UIButtonTypeInfoLight 
    target:self action:@selector(qrScanButtonPressed)]; 
    [[self navigationItem] setLeftBarButtonItem: qrScanButton];
    [qrScanButton release];
```

It seems from the error that the issue is with

> style: UIButtonTypeInfoLight

If I comment out the whole block then the code compiles fine. It stops working when the file type becomes .mm. This is a pretty standard block of code for adding alternative back buttons etc.

If anyone has any ideas how to resolve, I would really appreciate it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that "UIButtonTypeInfoLight" is not a valid [UIBarButtonItemStyle](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIBarButtonItem_Class/Reference/Reference.html). (Search for the UIBarButtonItemStyle constants at the bottom of the above link.)

The valid values are currently (iOS 4.2):

- UIBarButtonItemStylePlain
- UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered
- UIBarButtonItemStyleDone

You're passing in UIButtonTypeInfoLight, which is a [UIButtonType](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIButton_Class/UIButton/UIButton.html) and meaningless in the scope of a UIBarButtonItem.